# Get data web site

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create an automatic system to collect the data from web site. I try to wrute the following code in Excel using a macro but it doen't work. My problem in this case is in the Dim Url. If I play the macro the origin is only the write Url, I don't know how to solve it.

```
   Sub Recupera_dati()

Dim dtToday As Date
Dim Anno As String
Dim Url As String

    Anno = "2023"
    Mese = "Novembre"
    
Url = "https://www.ilmeteo.it/portale/archivio-meteo/Momo/" & Anno & "/" & Mese

'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=Mese & Anno, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origine = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""Url""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Origine{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Modificato tipo"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Giorno"", Int64.Type}, {""T Media"", type text}, {""T min"", type text}, {""T max"", type text}, {""Precip."", type text}, {""Umidità"", type text}, {""Vento M" & _
        "ax"", type text}, {""Raffica"", type text}, {""Fenomeni"", type text}, {""Info"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Modificato tipo"""
 
'Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Mese & Anno;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Mese & Anno]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = Mese
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `Dim URL`. You don't have a table on the website called "Mese & Anno" - that should probably be `.CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & Mese & Anno & "]")`

Comment: Same problem with your `Source:=` try         `"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & Mese & Anno & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable`

Comment: It looks like it should be `Origine = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""" & Url & """))," & Chr(13) . . . `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The issure is how to concatenate string with quotation marks.

Changes on:

- Formula argument in Queries.Add
- Source argument in ListObjects.Add
- CommandText argument in ListObjects.Add

```vb
Sub Recupera_dati()
    Dim dtToday As Date
    Dim Anno As String
    Dim Url As String
    Dim sQry As String
        Anno = "2023"
        Mese = "Novembre"
    Url = "https://www.ilmeteo.it/portale/archivio-meteo/Momo/" & Anno & "/" & Mese
    sQry = Mese & Anno
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=sQry, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origine = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""" & Url & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "    Data2 = Origine{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Modificato tipo"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Giorno"", Int64.Type}, {""T Media"", type text}, " & _
        "{""T min"", type text}, {""T max"", type text}, {""Precip."", type text}, {""Umidit¨¤"", type text}, {""Vento Max"", type text}," & _
        " {""Raffica"", type text}, {""Fenomeni"", type text}, {""Info"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Modificato tipo"""
    'Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & sQry & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & sQry & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = Mese
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

- Actually, the query formula can be simplified as below.

```vb
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=sQry, Formula:= _
        "let in Source=Web.Page(Web.Contents(""" & Url & """)){2}[Data]"
```